# Will using an external hard drive as a scratch disk improve the performance when running Adobe Apps?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

Would buying an external hard drive such as the SanDisk SDSSDE81-1T00-G25 Extreme Pro 1TB Portable NVMe SSD, USB-C, up to 1000MB/s and using it as a scratch disk help to improve the performance of running Adobe Illustrator and or Adobe Photoshop?

Here's why I ask:
Towards the end of 2020 my late 2013 iMac was upgraded from 8GB of RAM to 16GB of RAM. The internal hard drive was replaced with a 1TB SSD so that I could use Adobe Illustrator and Adobe Photoshop.

[image]

After Adobe released their newest software update my iMac was giving me the beach balls when I use Adobe Illustrator and or Adobe Photoshop. One Adobe representative told me it was my graphics card causing the issue.

I spoke with a computer technician and was told an external graphics card will cost $1000-$3000 depending on the make and model. Is there something else I can do to help improve the performance of my iMac?

Your advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: **Any** *external* drive used as a scratch disc will **not** improve performance to any noticeable degree. There is a latency when writing to external drives... that latency will work in direct contradiction to the activity used by scratch drives. Chances are **if** your iMac supports OS 11 or OS 12, upgrading to one of those will improve performance far more than an external scratch drive. -- Hardware issues are off-topic here. (not sure **how** one would use an "external graphic card" with **any** iMac - that point seem moot) Note 2013 is unfortunately *ancient* nowadays...

Comment: Ideally one sticks with the Adobe versions designed for a particular OS. You may get better performance out of Adobe's CC 2019 or 2020 than you will out of CC 2021 or 2022. Newer isn't *always* "better". Both Adobe and Apple make money by making you *think* you need the "latest and greatest", that's really rarely the case.

Comment: I don’t think that Mac can take an eGPU, nor  a newer OS.  Any external drive will be slower.. I think you’ve gone as far as you can with that machine.

Comment: @Scott, thank you for your advice. My late 2013 iMac has been wonderful for basic tasks but when it comes to creating heavy artwork in Illustrator or Photoshop it doesn't cope. Many years back my family purchased a refurbished computer and it caught on fire not long after the short warranty period expired. So we haven't felt confident buying second hand computers. I wasn't aware that I was able to install a previous version of Adobe which would be more compatible with my Mac's current OS. I'm not able to download OS11 or OS12 to run my late 2013 iMac.

Comment: @Tetsujin thank you for your feedback. I agree with you. It looks like I may need to use Affinity Designer instead of Adobe Creative Cloud until I am able to upgrade my iMac.

Answer (score 1):

Anything external is arguably slower than anything internal, so ***no***, you should ***not*** expect a major improvement by using external drives.

Most likely slower performance.

Comment: It's good to know this.  Too often people buy external hard drives hoping that they can use it to boost the performance of an older machine.